# Spring Autoconfig order/precedence on Profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've just been reading through some of the Spring documentation and I have a question about the way the autoconfigs work. So if we run a Java app with specific profiles, it will automatically use profiles that are named in the format:

```
application-{{profileName}}.properties
```

So lets say I'm running the application with the profiles dev and personal. This means that the following properties files with be run:
application.properties, application-dev.properties, and application-personal.properties. I'm confused as to how spring determines the precedence of these profiles. Like, if I define something in dev that overwrites personal, which one will be used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot uses your defaut profile *default* then overrides it sequentially with the profiles you listed.

For example, if you specify in your *application.properties* :

```
spring.profiles.active=dev,personnal
key1=default-value1
key2=default-value2
key3=default-value3
```

All values defined in *personnal* profile will override those from *dev* and *default*.

*application-dev.properties* :

```
key2=dev-value2
key3=dev-value3
```

*application-personnal.properties* :

```
key3=personnal-value3
```

Your app will match theses values :

```
key1=default-value1
key2=dev-value2
key3=personnal-value3
```

You can also use *spring.profiles.include* in *application-personnal.properties* to unconditionnally include *dev* profile in *personnal* profile for example :

```
spring.profiles.include=dev
```

Regards

Answer (score -1):

You can think of `application.properties` file as 'file of default values'.

When you specify a profile on bootstrap, for example 'dev', first of all, `application.properties` file is processed, after that, these values are overwritten by values imported from `application-dev.properties` file. So values on 'application-personal.properties' are not imported.