# Spring Profiles application properties order

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

We have many environments that have multiple active Spring profiles, but what is the precedence of the application-{profile}.yml files?

If I have `spring.profiles.active=test-us-west-2-p1, test-us-west-2, test`

In what order do the files `application-test.yml, application-test-us-west-2.yml, application-test-us-west-2-p1.yml` get loaded?  If I have the same property in each file, which "wins"?

Also, has this changed from Spring-Boot 1.5.x to 2.x?  It seems like it may have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Autoconfig order/precedence on Profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062754/spring-autoconfig-order-precedence-on-profiles)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The profile's properties are loaded in the same order as you specify them, and if the same property is defined in different profiles the last one wins.

This behavior applies to both Spring Boot versions 1.5.x and 2.x, and if I recall correctly, it applies to all versions of Spring.

Spring always loads appication.yml. And afterwards, if some profile is specified, it will load that profile's property file. And if after that profile another profile is specified, it will load that profile's propperty file. Always overriding current properties's value with the new one.

So, let's say you have profile1 and profile2. And you have these property files:

application.yml:

```
property1: bob
property2: alice
property3: eve
```

application-profile1.yml:

```
property2: alice1
property3: eve1
```

application-profile2.yml:

```
property3: eve2
```

And you start your application with: `spring.profiles.active=profile1, profile2`

Your will get:

```
property1: bob
property2: alice1
property3: eve2
```

Comment: **NOT ALWAYS**. Properties in an application.yaml that is provided *outside* your app jar file will override same-name properties in application-{profile}.yaml that is packaged inside your jar. This rule is especially important if you're using spring-cloud-config.  See [official doc about external property precedence](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, we need to find out the final set of all active profiles. There are ways of *setting/replacing* active profiles and *adding* active profiles on top of existing active ones. For instance, active profiles set with the `spring.profiles.active` property are replaced with the `-Dspring.profiles.active` command line option. (And this can get really complex.)

On the other hand, the `SpringApplicationBuilder's` `profiles` method adds to the existing active profiles. We can use the following code to figure out the final set of active profiles:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

...

System.out.println("Active profiles: " +
        Arrays.toString(environment.getActiveProfiles()));
```

Now we have to consider what Spring documentation calls **last-wins strategy**.

> If several profiles are specified, a last-wins strategy applies.

So, if we have the following code and all other options excluded:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
        .profiles("dev", "prod")
        .run(args);
```

both `application-dev.properties` and `application-prod.properties` files are loaded and the keys with the same name in the latter one (the production) override the former one.

Answer (score 0):

I posted important notice on profiles order handling. See how jar resources files are handled in this process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62222879/1948151).